# Unable to click SubMenu using selenium web driver

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am exploring options to automate UI application. I have menu which will display sub menu on mouse over . I am unable to click on Sub menu items.

### Below is my html code.

```
<table class="mnuAdmin_2" id="mnuAdmin" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td id="mnuAdminn0" 
                onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" 
                onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)">

                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
                    <tbody>
                       <tr>         
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                              <a class="mnuAdmin_1" style="cursor: text;" href="#">
                                 <img style="vertical-align: middle;
                                             border-top-style: none; 
                                             border-right-style: none; 
                                             border-bottom-style: none; 
                                             border-left-style: none;" 
                                      alt="" 
                                      src="Images/icon_administration.gif" />
                                Administration</a>
                            </td>           
                        </tr>       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="mnuAdmin_0 dynamicMenu mnuAdmin_5" 
     id="mnuAdminn0Items" 
     style="left: 165px; 
            top: 23px; 
            height: 101px; 
            display: inline; 
            visibility: visible; 
            z-index: 100; 
            clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);">
    <table style="top: 0px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">       
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr title="Test1" 
                id="mnuAdminn1" 
                onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" 
                onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)">       
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" 
                           class="mnuAdmin_4" 
                           border="0" 
                           cellspacing="0" 
                           cellpadding="0">         
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>                
                                <td style="width: 100%; 
                                           white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <a class="mnuAdmin_1 mnuAdmin_3" 
                                       href="javascript:openNewTabs(' Test1.aspx', 
                                                                    ' Test1',
                                                                    ' Test1',
                                                                      false)">
                                        <div class="menuPadding">
                                            Test1
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </td>           
                            </tr>           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>       
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">       
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">       
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr title="Manage NICE Group" 
                id="mnuAdminn2" 
                onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" 
                onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" 
                onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)">       
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" 
                           class="mnuAdmin_4" 
                           border="0" 
                           cellspacing="0" 
                           cellpadding="0">         
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>                
                                <td style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <a class="mnuAdmin_1 mnuAdmin_3"
                                       href="javascript:openNewTabs('Test2.aspx',
                                                                    'Test2',
                                                                    'Test2',
                                                                     false)">
                                        <div class="menuPadding">
                                            Test2
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </td>           
                            </tr>       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">       
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">       
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr id="mnuAdminn3" 
                onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" 
                onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" 
                onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)">   
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" 
                           class="mnuAdmin_4" 
                           border="0" 
                           cellspacing="0" 
                           cellpadding="0">         
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>                
                                <td style="width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <a class="mnuAdmin_1 mnuAdmin_3" 
                                       style="cursor: text;" 
                                       href="#">
                                        <div class="menuPadding">
                                            Test3
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 0px;">
                                    <img style="vertical-align: middle; 
                                                border-top-style: none; 
                                                border-right-style: none; 
                                                border-bottom-style: none; 
                                                border-left-style: none;" 
                                         alt="Expand" 
                                         src="/abc/WebResource.axd?
                                             d=Q47Az1X7LOaP01DStAi2pDvM8t2PM3
                                               zBTfT7Sah9glcZvljgU_O4sclltCDWejo
                                               5HwZg0ZVGfOiJikirBgVVmAah_spY2-
                                               yjejh4oSaW2XbzOqmK0&t=635294807132453548" />
                                </td>       
                            </tr>       
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;">   
                <td></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 1px;"> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried following two options.

1. var element = driverIE.FindElement(By.LinkText("Administration"));
           Actions action = new Actions(driverIE);

   ```
       action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
       driverIE.FindElement(By.LinkText("Test2")).Click();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();

Thread.sleep(5000L);

driverIE.FindElement(By.LinkText("Test2")).Click();

I think we should give some seconds to sub menu to open.